# How to make animated LaunchScreen in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have completed the iOS development course but in my course, I didn't find any animated launch screen. I want to add some animations to my app launching scene and add some delay because it opens so fast. So, is it possible to do this thing without creating a new class?  I searched about this question but didn't find exactly what I want.

Comment: what you need to do is to make a controller for that after launch you navigate to that controller that show animation and then go to other screen

Comment: Beware of putting too much delay into your start up. Ideally people should be able to tap to skip your animation and get to using your app.

Comment: from LaunchScreen.storyboard you can't do that only you can add static elements like text or image and can't animate any of them, if you need to do animation you have to create a view controller and make it your launch screen and do your animation whether using code to animate or use gif and after the animation finished go to another view

Comment: Did you mean adding new class for launchscreen?